# Visual studio publish to azure Error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

[image: Error]

I did some research before posting. I think it has to do with publishing the project from a different workspace and namespace.  Regardless, I tried deleting the bin manually, cleaning the project, rebuilding and publishing, however nothing seems to work.